# How to solve $(k-\sqrt{k^2-4y^2})- 10sin^2((m -y)/5)= 0$ and how to embed the solution of equations in other formulas

Tags: functions, notation

I have a formula like this $5-\sqrt{25 -4 x^2}$, and I know that the value of $x$ is the solution to a rather complicated equation 
$$(k-\sqrt{k^2-4y^2})- 10sin^2((m -y)/5)= 0 $$

**The (only) solution to this equation equals**: $y= (k=) x$

I do not know how to deal with an equation that contains both $x$ and $\sin^2(x)$

> **1)-** Is there a possibility of embedding the equation in the formula so that$5-\sqrt{25 -4* ({\text equation})^2}$
>
> **2)-** I can use the formula as a function in calculators to find integral, etc..?
>   Thanks
>
> **3)-** How to solve the equation $(k-\sqrt{k^2-4y^2})- 10sin^2((m -y)/5)= 0$?

P.S. please don't downvote my question, I am just a high-school student

Comment: What are you asking? You want to substitute? Just write $p=5-\sqrt{25-4x^2}$ and now you can use $p$! Or any other letter, we have loads of them, when they've run out we have funky versions, like $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathbb{X}$

Comment: I'm not really sure but  talking about the general case: I think often the set of solutions of some equation can be empty or it can have more than one member. That means that often you substitute your $x$ with a set of values, not a single value.
Let $f(x)=0$ an equation: the set of solutions is the *preimage* of $0$ under $f$. You can denote that set with $f^{-1}\{0\}$ the you can put it in your initial formula...but $f^{-1}\{0\}$ can also be empty..

Comment: @AlecTeal, is it OK now?,what info is lacking, please?

Comment: @AlecTeal I don't understand your first comment, Anyways what the OP is asking is clear imho.

Comment: @MphLee,I am glad you understand the question, there is only one solution for every value of x in the interval I need (0<x<5)

Comment: @MphLee you're committed to answering now. Frank, I leave you in this guy's magical hands.

Comment: There are two question btw, I'm going to edit it @frank. If you want you can reset my edit.

Comment: @MphLee, can you rewrite the equation in the form x = ....? If you can I think that solves the problem, doesn't it?

Comment: @frank but you are also asking a solution for the equation! You should then edit your question...You are asking three different things:
1)-How to embed, with mathematical notation, the solution of an equation into a formula
2)-If you can put the formula into a calculator
3)-How to solve your equation

Question 1),2) are clearly stated...but if you need an explaination on how to solve that equation you should edit your question.

Comment: @MphLee help the OP, you got the question after all.

Comment: @MphLee, my comment was sparked by *Alec* (I suppose) hinting it is impossible. If I can embed the equation in any fashion I am happy with it. If it is impossible I suppose that one can always substitute x with the equivalent expression, am I right in thinking that, one way or another, there is a way of solving the problem?

Comment: @Alec, I regret  your comments are above me, but can you tell me if there is a possibility of solving my problem, in any way that I can feed a function into an integral calculator?

Comment: @frank I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Like what does $\rightarrow$ mean here? If you explain more I can help certainly.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: @AlecTeal,I edited the question, is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

***I can only answer to your first question.***
Let $h(x)$ be a function and let $f(x)=0$ be an equation.

If I understand, your first question asks if it is possible to embed graphically (using mathematical notation) the solution of the equation $f(x)=0$ in the function $h(x)$. $$h({\rm SOLUTIONS}[f(x)=0])$$

Well it is possible.

We call *preimage* of $0$ by $f$ the set of $x$'s such that $f(x)=0$ and denote it by $f^{-1}\{0\}$ $$f^{-1}\{0\}:=\{x:f(x)=0\}$$

We then define the *image* of a set $X$ ($X$ must be a subset of the domain of $h$) by a function $h$ to be the set of $h(x)$'s such that $x\in X$ and denote it by $h[X]$ $$h[X]:=\{h(x):x\in X\}$$

Now we can "insert" the solutions of the equation $f(x)=0$ as an argument of the fucntion $h$

$$h[f^{-1}\{0\}]$$

About the second question: have you tried some softwares like mathematica or asking wolfram alpha?

Comment: Thanks, could you write down the actual formula? I have no access to mathematica, and wolfram just gives [*the result*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve++5-sqrt%2825-4x^2%29+%3D+10sin^2%28%283.108752772-x%29%2F5%29), does not say how they did it

Answer (score 1):

> *I do not know how to deal with an equation that contains both x and $\sin^2(x)$*

[No one does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) $\ldots$

---

> *How to solve the equation* $\Big(k-\sqrt{k^2-4y^2}\Big)-10\sin^2\bigg(\dfrac{m-y}5\bigg)=0$ ?

Let $y=\dfrac k2~\sin t,~$ with $t\in\bigg[0,~\dfrac\pi2\bigg].~$ Then, for $k>0$ we have $$\color{red}t=\arccos\bigg[1-\dfrac{10}k~\sin^2\bigg(\dfrac{2m-k\sin\color{red}t}{10}\bigg)\bigg],$$ and for $k<0,\quad\color{red}t=\arccos\bigg[\dfrac{10}k~\sin^2\bigg(\dfrac{2m-k\sin\color{red}t}{10}\bigg)-1\bigg].~$ Both expressions are recursive

in nature, so let $t_0=\dfrac\pi4,$ and then iterate using the appropriate above formula.